# Remove icons from KDE task manager

Tags: kde, task-manager, kde-4

How do I remove these icons from KDE's task manager?

[image]

I am using KDE 4.8 on Arch Linux, I've looked everywhere but I cannot for the life of me find out how to remove them

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it

Open the following

```
~/.kde4/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc
```

and remove

```
[Containments][1][Applets][5][Configuration][Launchers]
Items=preferred://browser?wmClass=%20,preferred://filemanager?wmClass=%20
browser=preferred://browser, , ,\s
filemanager=preferred://filemanager, , ,\s
```

Then log out and back in and the icons will be gone

Answer (score 2):

less hacky solution in KDE 5:
right-click on taskbar near this shortcuts and choose "Panel Options/Panel Settings" from menu. Then right click the icon you want to remove and click "remove this icon"